# Process text commands using SRGS grammar in c#

Tags: c#, uwp, voice-recognition, srgs

I developed a UWP app with `Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition`, which is able to take voice commands and process them using SRGS grammar. I want to give the user an option to type commands as well. Is there a way I can process these commands entered by user using same SRGS grammar?

Comment: You should be able know that `SRGS` is Speech Recognition Grammar Specification. What  do you want to do for text with **speech** grammar? Could you please detail your question?

Comment: Yes, I know SRGS is meant for speech recognition. I want to give a feature where user can also type and give instructions. In this case I need to write a logic to convert the free text entered by user to a command. I was wondering if framework has exposed any class which can consume SRGS grammar (which is working fine for voice commands) and do this out of box.

Comment: "where user can also type and give instructions" please detail that. For example, type what, expect what. Again, SRGS is speech grammar, you should not use it for text. You should know what similar feature from SRGS did  you want to implement  by text. You could try to implement the features by yourself and if you met some issues, ask with details.